# Pester Mocking CmdLets

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have question regarding to the mocking mechanism in Pester. I have a script `Script.ps1` that I want to test. The tests are located in `Script.Tests.ps1`. In `Script.ps1` I implemented the following function:

```
function Start-Executable {
    param([string]$Executable)

    Start-Process $Executable
}
```

For testing purpose I want to mock `Start-Process`. The `Script.Tests.ps1` contains the following test.

```
BeforeAll{
   . $PSScriptRoot/Script.ps1
}

Describe 'Start-Executable' {
    Mock -CommandName 'Start-Process' -MockWith {return $null}
    
    It 'Start-Process is called.'{

       Start-Executable -Executable 'Test.exe'
       Assert-MockCalled 'Start-Process'
    }
}
```

If I execute the test, the real `Start-Process` throws an exception that 'Test.exe' could not be found. If I move the mock in the It-block, the test passes. I would like to add the mock in the Describe-block (or later, as more tests are getting written, in the Context-block) to have one mock covering a bench of tests. Is this possible and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're probably using Pester v5. As such your mock needs to be in a `BeforeAll` or `BeforeEach` block.

This should work:

```
BeforeAll{
   . $PSScriptRoot/Script.ps1
}

Describe 'Start-Executable' {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock -CommandName 'Start-Process' -MockWith {return $null}
    }

    It 'Start-Process is called.'{

       Start-Executable -Executable 'Test.exe'
       Assert-MockCalled 'Start-Process'
    }
}
```

> All code placed in the body of Describe outside of It, BeforeAll,
> BeforeEach, AfterAll, AfterEach will run during discovery and it's
> state might or might not be available to the test code, see Discovery
> and Run
>
> -- https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/migrations/breaking-changes-in-v5

Comment: If I want to add a second mock, must it be placed also in the BeforeAll block?

Comment: Yes. But if you want to Mock the same command in different ways you can define them inside separate `BeforeAll` blocks inside different `Context` blocks. Another way to make different Mocks fire for different circumstances is to use a ParameterFilter so a Mock is only matched if the command is invoked with a certain set of parameters.